# How to collect all alterationof /proc/pid/pagemap in Linux

Tags: linux-kernel

I want to know all the virtual to physical address map information for a specific progress for all its life. So one way is to get all the alteration of the pagemap which is changing all the time.
    One way come to me is to read the pagemap using loop to detect whether current pagemap is exactly the same as the former. If this realizable? or any other suggestions is appreciated. Thanks 
Adam

Comment: why do you need this in userspace? the information about mapping will be out of date at the moment when you will read it.

Comment: Thanks Alex for your reply, I want to get all virtual to physical mapping for a specific progress during its lifetime. Is there any other way to do so? Thanks.